# Вывести массив в виде строки

Tags: php, массивы

```
<?php
  $strings = ["v", 'g', 'a'];
  sort($strings);
  print_r($strings);
?>
```

Данный код выводит

```
Array ( 
   [0] => a 
   [1] => g 
   [2] => v 
)
```

а как сделать, чтобы он выводил `а, g, v` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вместо

```
print_r ($strings);
```

используйте

```
echo join(",",$strings);
```

и таки да, sort работает ))

Comment: Спасибо вам за доброту!

Comment: `join` считается "deprecated", кодоанализаторы советуют использовать `implode` с тем же синтаксисом

Comment: использую join он короче и очевиднее имхо
хотя раньше юзал implode

Comment: @Явжизни _Спасибо вам за доброту!_ Лучше отметьте ответ, как решение проблемы. Галочка слева

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $strings =["v", 'g', 'a'];
   sort($strings);
   for($i = 0; $i < count($strings); $i++){
       echo $strings[$i];
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант с использованием implode(http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php):

```
$strings = ["v", 'g', 'a'];
sort($strings);
$strings = implode(",", $strings);
print_r($strings);
```